# Spring Webflux : mutual authentication fails on second request

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, mutual-authentication

I am in a context of TLS mutual authentication (server certificate and client certificate).

My client is a Spring Boot application with webflux (WebClient).
The WebClient instance is created once and for all (the client runs as a service 24/24h).

My server is also a Spring Boot application configured for mutual authentication.

The first request works like a charm.

The second request (about 10 minutes later) always fails with the following error on client side :

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error
        at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:133) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:356) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:293) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:202) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:171) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.decode(SSLEngineImpl.java:736) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:691) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:506) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:482) ~[?:?]
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:679) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$3.unwrap(SslHandler.java:297) ~[netty-handler-4.1.89.Final.jar!/:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1352) ~[netty-handler-4.1.89.Final.jar!/:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1245) ~[netty-handler-4.1.89.Final.jar!/:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1294) ~[netty-handler-4.1.89.Final.jar!/:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:529) ~[netty-codec-4.1.89.Final.jar!/:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:468) ~[netty-codec-4.1.89.Final.jar!/:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290) ~[netty-codec-4.1.89.Final.jar!/:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar!/:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar!/:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar!/:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar!/:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar!/:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar!/:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar!/:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:800) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.89.Final.jar!/:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:499) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.89.Final.jar!/:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:397) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.89.Final.jar!/:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.89.Final.jar!/:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.89.Final.jar!/:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.89.Final.jar!/:4.1.89.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) [?:?]
```

... and the following error on server side :

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.TLSClientHelloExtractor The ClientHello was not presented in a single TLS record so no SNI information could be extracted
```

I suppose the server expects the client to authenticate again and I suppose the client does not feel the need to authenticate again.

Do I need to configure further my WebClient in order to maintain the connection open or something like that ?

I could recreate the WebClient for every request but I think it's not necessar with the proper configuration.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this issue.

This was the faulty code for WebClient instanciation:

```java
var keyStoreInputStream = keyStoreResource.getInputStream();
var keyStore = readKeyStore(keyStoreType, keyStoreInputStream, keyStorePassword);
var keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(getDefaultAlgorithm());
keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, keyStorePassword);

var trustStoreInputStream = trustStoreResource.getInputStream();
var trustStore = readKeyStore(trustStoreType, trustStoreInputStream, trustStorePassword);
var trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(getDefaultAlgorithm());
trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);

var sslContext = forClient().
        keyManager(keyManagerFactory).
        trustManager(trustManagerFactory).
        build();

var httpClient = HttpClient.create().
        secure(ssl -> ssl.sslContext(sslContext));

var clientConnector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);

var webClient = WebClient.builder().
        clientConnector(clientConnector).
        baseUrl(baseUrl).
        build();
```

With this configuration, the underlying channel is closed after 60 seconds of inactivity (without requests). I don't know if it's due to the client or server configuration.

Once the channel is closed, if I do another request, it automatically opens a new channel but it reuses the same SSL session. That's why the client does not perform a new SSL handshake. That's why I got the following error on server side:

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.TLSClientHelloExtractor The ClientHello was not presented in a single TLS record so no SNI information could be extracted
```

My idea to fix this issue was to make the SSL session expire BEFORE the channel does with this additional SSL context configuration:

```java
var sslContext = forClient().
        keyManager(keyManagerFactory).
        trustManager(trustManagerFactory).
        sessionTimeout(30).
        build();
```

It happens to work, the SSL session times out before the channel does and the SSL handshake is performed again if necessary.

I think it's not a very clean solution and I'm still open to suggestions but I consider this issue as fixed.